# Complex equation in maxima

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

I rested on [this tutorial.](http://www.hippasus.com/resources/symmath/maximasym.html)

After issuing the command with "solve" function:

```
%i2 solve((a-b-sqrt(-c^2+2*c*y-y^2+r^2))^2+(d-y)^2=2*r^2*(1-cos(e)),y);
```

The output is: [image]

Why there is unknown quantity "y" on the right side?

P.S.

There's no "Maxima" tag, what a pity! However, I was redirected here by a stackoverflow moderator, so I assume it is not offtopic.

> Maxima is a computer algebra system based on a 1982 version of
>   Macsyma. It is written in Common Lisp and runs on all POSIX platforms
>   such as Mac OS X, Unix, BSD, and GNU/Linux as well as under Microsoft
>   Windows. It is free software released under the terms of the GNU
>   General Public License.
>   
>   source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_%28software%29

Comment: Clearly, Maxima was not entirely successful at isolating the variable you want...

Comment: @J.M. Was it my fault?

Comment: W|A spits out a pretty lengthy result that doesn't seem to have $y=$ (something with $y$ in it)...

Comment: @TheChaz there are two "y" under the square root. Or this "W|A" shortcut which I don't understand (google also doesn't know anything about "W|A maxima") is significant.

Comment: I copied your code "solve(...,y)" into www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: @kowalt, that I cannot say; I do not have the thing installed on my computer to evaluate this properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general solve command in Macsyma has limited capabilities for dealing with algebraic functions. You can work around this by using the rational function package as in the code below. There I define w to be the sqrt, then solve for w, square, then solve for y.

> (algebraic:true, tellrat( w^2 = -c^2+2*c*y-y^2+r^2 ));
>
> solve(rat(solve(rat((a-b-w)^2+(d-y)^2 = 2*r^2*(1-cos(e))),w)^2),y)

Comment: This is useful.

Comment: The result is five lines long, like in the wolframalpha.com.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  Could you explain a little more what rat() and tellrat() are doing here and why these steps are used.  I was able to solve an equation with this method but I'm bother that I don't really understand why it works.